# How to add multiple records from a loop in Excel?

Tags: node.js, excel4node

Need to add multiple records from a loop in Excel. According to the given parameters, it adds to the first column and to the first row.  What needs to be replaced by `worksheet.cell(1, 1)` to add entries to the first column and to all subsequent rows?

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    worksheet.cell(1, 1).string(users[i].NAME).style(style);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, it will add each user to a new row (in column 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    worksheet.cell(i + 1, 1).string(users[i].NAME).style(style);
}
```

You can also use a forEach loop if you prefer:

```
users.forEach((user, index) => worksheet.cell(index + 1, 1).string(user.NAME).style(style));
```